# How to send my Java generated logs to ELK

Tags: java, microservices, logstash, elk

I am currently working on a microservices based project. What I want to do is to be able to send my logs generated by a Java service running in a Docker container to ELK, which is a separate Docker container. What is the best way to do that?
I was hoping I could send my logs through HTTP directly to the ELK stack, instead of saving the logs into a file locally.

My Java service uses Java 1.8, Spring Boot and it uses slf4j for logging.

Comment: Actually your service can’t use slf4j for logging. Slf4j only provides common interface for logging framework. Underneath it probably will be logback, java.util.logging or log4j

Comment: You're right. I am using log4j underneath

Answer (score 2):

You should use Filebeat to send logs to your ELK. You can read how to setup it for docker container [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-container.html)

Comment: Adding to this: shipping logs from your process directly to your log aggregator (e.g. via a custom log appender in, e.g. logback) is virtually certain to eventually bite you because the shipping will be consuming resources shared with your application.  Using the filesystem within the container as a buffer to let filebeat asynchronously ship the logs at least reduces the resource-sharing (I recommend, if committing to this, running filebeat on the host so it's not using the container's resources).

Comment: Also adding: I highly recommend having your application log in logstash-structured JSON (there's a well-done encoder for this for logback) and configuring filebeat and logstash to just pass such logs through to Elasticsearch instead of trying to grok them.  Doing this means your SLF4J MDC becomes fields in the JSON which will give you superpowers in Kibana.